# How to export a procedure outside designer in C# / VS Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I'm a complete newbie with C# and VS Community, while i'm not really a newbie in OOP and programmation in general. I'm just trying to dig into my 20-years-old lack of update into best pratices ... While i'm happy with my mammoth aged skills in C or HDL ...

I'have done a micro-solution to text the size of a set of files with this code :

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of the open file dialog box.
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        DialogResult userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (userClickedOK == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.Stream test = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            var size = test.Length.ToString();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Format("Size: {0} bytes", size);
        }
```

I want to transform the portion of code that deals with action to do `if userClickedOK == DialogResult.OK` with something like this :

```
if (userClickedOK == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            something.do();
        }
```

And my question is .... *tada* ... where (in wich file or via which menu) do i declare the class *something* and the procedure *do* ?

I apologize, but i'm ready with vi and nano, but IDEs are tools made by wizzards for wizzards ...

Comment: Are you going to want the procedure to be able to update your form, as per the existing line `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Format("Size: {0} bytes", size);`?

Comment: no...he wants to know where he hast to write `public class Something { public void do(){}}`

Comment: @stuartd, yes you're right !

Comment: @Raindator, you're true again, your answer replies my question too ! I barerly want the class to be integrated into a lib, statically linked, and then I go where I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code running you have to either add a extra file (Code file) to your project in which you code your class and implement your functions or you take your main.cs file and insert your code after the main class

To add another file just press `Ctr + Shift + A` or go to `Project -> Add Class -> Class -> Edit Name -> Add`

Then open the file from the solution explorer and make your implementation

To make your class and the functions available from a DLL, simply do the same but make sure your class Something is public. then you cann add a reference from another project to your *.exe and import the namespace for using and instanciating the class

Comment: Well documented, thank you Radinator :) I wanted to add a new class, i had to hit buttons ADD, then NEW CLASS ... Those IDE are fantastics ... But they need at last a mouse and some form of ... abnegation, I guess :)